# Complexity of planted root of a system of quadratic homogeneous polynomials?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-complexity, sum-of-squares

Given homogeneous degree $2$ randomly chosen polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_{m}$ in $\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n]$ each with only monomials $x_iy_j$ with condition that the system $f_1=\dots=f_{m}=0$ has an unique common root in $\mathbb Z^{2n}\backslash\{{(0,\dots,0)}\}$ upto sign and exchange of $x$ and $y$ variables we can extract the root with elimination theory in $2^{O(n)}poly(\max\log\|f_i\|_\infty)$ time if $m=2n$ holds. Assume we have $m=poly(n)$ random equations (note only any $2n$ of them can be algebrically independent and they will be so with high propbaility).

1. Is there an approach that can give $O(poly(n)poly(\max\log\|f_i\|_\infty))$ time?
2. What conditions are on the polynomials are needed to extract the unique root in $O(poly(n))poly(\max\log\|f_i\|_\infty)$ time in case roots 1. does not have a general algorithm?

Is this approachable using Sum-of-squares? Note $f_i^2$ are all non-negative and have same integer roots.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm curious as to the motivation?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow The motivation is circuitous and I can communicate privately if interested.

Comment: Sure, I'd be curious to hear.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Ok I will send you email. However do you think this can be solved?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I have completed documentation of this. May I send information on this approach?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow sent.